# Mixing graphics in NSTextView?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextview

I thought I read somewhere that there is a way to embed drawings or other non-text in a text view, but I can't find anything about it in the Apple documentation.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I'm trying to build an editor, not just a view.  I'm imagining a special character in the underlying text, and based on text attributes, it would reserves some blank space in the text layout. ?  Or maybe I need to layout blocks myself, using NSTextContainers and a custom NSView to flow text around graphics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into the NSTextAttachment and NSTextAttachmentCell. You can do your own custom drawing when you subclass the NSTextAttachmentCell.

Apple docs: [Text Attachment Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextAttachments/TextAttachments.html)