# Is it possible to have floating images or text boxes in an NSTextView or what would I use to do that?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am experimenting with a word processor I am making and is curious if it is possible to have floating images or text boxes (not inline with text) in an NSTextView. If that isn't possible what would I have to use to go in that direction?

Answer (score 1):

For images (or arbitrary views, really), you can use an `NSTextAttachment` and `NSTextAttachmentCell`. There are a couple of other questions on Stack Overflow about them like [NSTextView insert image in between text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300427/nstextview-insert-image-in-between-text) or [Mixing graphics in NSTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404765/mixing-graphics-in-nstextview).

Depending on what you mean by "floating", you might have to develop [a custom `NSTextContainer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Concepts/CalcTextLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000847-CJBBIAAF).